# How do I uncheck a jquery checkbox and have the remaining checkbox'd results still available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, filter

As you can see in the link, when you uncheck "ALL GAMES", all of the results go hidden, even though there are still checkboxes checked with the necessary list result to be shown.

I am trying to avoid removing all results when I uncheck the all games checkbox.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jCpe8/)

The HTML:

```
<div id="left-col">
    <h1>Options</h1>

    <div>
        <input name="action-areas[]" id="areas_all" value="4" class="type_check" type="checkbox">
        <label for="areas_all">ALL GAMES</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="action-areas[]" id="areas_2D" value="0" class="type_check" type="checkbox">
        <label for="areas_2D">2D</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="action-areas[]" id="areas_3D" value="1" class="type_check" type="checkbox">
        <label for="areas_3D">3D</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="action-areas[]" id="areas_mobile" value="2" class="type_check" type="checkbox">
        <label for="areas_mobile">Mobile</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="action-areas[]" id="areas_multiplayer" value="3" class="type_check" type="checkbox">
        <label for="areas_multiplayer">Multiplayer</label>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="right-col">
<h1>List items</h1>
    <ul id="case-studies">
        <li  class="type_hidden areas_all areas_2D">Super Mario Bros.</li>
        <li  class="type_hidden areas_all areas_3D">StarFox</li>
        <li  class="type_hidden areas_all areas_2D areas_mobile">Angry Birds</li>
        <li  class="type_hidden areas_all areas_multiplayer areas_3D">de_dust</li>
        <li  class="type_hidden areas_all areas_2D">Limbo</li>
        <li  class="type_hidden areas_all areas_2D areas_3D areas_mobile">Doom</li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.type_check").attr("checked", "true").click(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#case-studies li."+$(this).attr('id')).removeClass('type_hidden');
            $("#case-studies li").not(".type_hidden, .start_hidden").slideDown();
        } else {
            $("#case-studies li."+$(this).attr('id')).addClass('type_hidden');
            $("#case-studies li."+$(this).attr('id')).slideUp();
        }
    });

    $("input.start_check").attr("checked", "").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#case-studies li."+$(this).attr('id')).removeClass('start_hidden');
            $("#case-studies li").not(".type_hidden, .start_hidden").slideDown();
        } else {
            $("#case-studies li."+$(this).attr('id')).addClass('start_hidden');
            $("#case-studies li."+$(this).attr('id')).slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: WHat should happen when you uncheck all results check box?

Comment: Only the results without the proper class should go away. In this instance, none should go away because 2D, 3D, mobile, and multiplayer are still checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var parts = $("input.type_check:not(#areas_all)");

    parts.click(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#case-studies li." + this.id).removeClass('type_hidden').slideDown();
        } else {
            var cls = parts.filter(':checked').map(function(){
                return '.' + this.id;
            }).get();
            $("#case-studies li").not(cls.join(',')).addClass('type_hidden').slideUp();;
        }
    });

    $('#areas_all').click(function(){
        parts.prop('checked', this.checked).each(function(){
            $(this).triggerHandler('click')
        })
    }).prop('checked', true).triggerHandler('click')

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jCpe8/14/)